Can I type a function return based on the items in an array parameter?
I’m working with an API pattern where calling a getItem function returns an item with a small number of properties.
{ id: 123, isBig: true }

I can also pass an array called properties into my getItem function to request additional properties.
getItem({ properties: ['color'])) should return { id: 123, isBig: true, color: 'red' }
My Item type has the additional properties as optional properties:
{ id: number, isBig: boolean, color?: 'string' )

I would like to be able to type my getItem function such that if I pass in { properties: ['color'] }, TypeScript can infer that the color property will be present on the return value.
My first thought was to use generics, something along the lines of this.
type APIFunction<TReturnType, TProperties extends (keyof TReturnType)[] =[]> = 
  (params: { properties: TProperties }) => // oops, what do we return here?

But this approach requires looping through the generic TProperties array and I don’t know that that’s possible. Is this something I can do in TypeScript?

Is this approach what you're looking for? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

In order for this to work, you'd need APIFunction<Item> to be a generic function; that is, the second type parameter (which corresponds roughly to your TProperties parameter) needs to move to the call signature, as follows:
type APIFunction<R> = <K extends keyof R>
    (params: { properties: K[] }) => R & Required<Pick<R, K>>;

So R is the expected basic return type of your function, and K is the union of keys passed in as the properties array.  Then the return type is R intersected with Required<Pick<R, K>> using the Required and Pick utility types to say that the return type is R with all of the properties at keys K definitely present.
Let's test it out:
type Item = { id: number, isBig: boolean, color?: string };

declare const getItem: APIFunction<Item>;
const item1 = getItem({ properties: [] });
item1.color.toUpperCase(); // error, possibly undefined

const item2 = getItem({ properties: ['color'] });
item2.color.toUpperCase(); // okay

Looks good. In the first case, item1 is of type Item & Required<Pick<Item, never>> which is equivalent to Item and so the color property is possibly undefined. In the second case, item2 is of type Item & Required<Pick<Item, "color">> which is Item & {color: string}, equivalent to { id: number, isBig: boolean, color: string }, so the color property is definitely defined.
Note that you'd probably need to implement getItem() separately from any other APIFunction<R> for other R types, since that implementation needs to know specifically that it's looking up Items from somewhere as opposed to some other types. But the implementation is out of scope for the question as asked.
Playground link to code

Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!
Could you explain (or link to documentation) for the syntax you're using in the <K extends keyof R> bit? I understand K extends keyof R but what does it do to have an expression in angle brackets at that point in the type declaration?

It's a generic function. If you have a generic function like declare function foo<T extends U>(x: T): F<T> then it has the call signature <T extends U>(x: T) => F<T> Does that make sense?  The type parameter is scoped to the call signature.

I came up with this generic.  I do make the assumption that the type of various properties is going to be a string, but you could easily strengthen that by mapping the possible properties and their expected types.  You would really need to strengthen the type as we can pass any old string in the array of properties.
I feel like you wanted the argument to getItem to be optional.
type Result = {
  id: number;
  isBig: boolean;
};

type Options<T extends string[]> = {
  [Key in keyof T as T[Key] & string]: string;
};

declare function getItem<const T extends string[]>(
  arg?: {properties:T},
): Options<T> & Result;

const ex1 = getItem();

ex1.id;
ex1.isBig;


const ex2 = getItem({properties:["color", "flower"]});
ex2.color;
ex2.flower;
ex2.id;
ex2.isBig;

https://tsplay.dev/mpMA6W
Edit Safer Optional Properties
Here is a tweak to the above code to make the available optional properties more type safe.
type Result = {
  id: number;
  isBig: boolean;
};

type Properties = {
  color: string;
  size: { x: number; y: number };
  origin: { x: number; y: number };
  isResizable: boolean;
};

type Options<T extends (keyof Properties)[]> = {
  [Key in keyof T]: Pick<Properties, T[Key]>;
}[number];

declare function getItem<T extends (keyof Properties)[]>(arg?: {
  properties: T;
}): Options<T> & Result;

const ex1 = getItem();

ex1.id;
ex1.isBig;

const ex2 = getItem({ properties: ["color", "origin", "size"] });
ex2.color;
ex2.size.x;
ex2.size.y;
ex2.origin.x;
ex2.origin.y;
ex2.id;
ex2.isBig;

Now the only optional properties you can request are color size origin isResizable  and now their expected types are defined.
